# ¿Cómo introduzco la condicional que hice de longitud dentro de una función en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, funciones

Si *nombre* y *apellido* tienen en total más de 15 letras queremos un cartelito corto solo con *titulo* y *apellido*, de lo contrario, queremos un cartelito largo con *titulo*, *nombre* y *apellido*.

Definí la función *escribirCartelitoOptimo* que toma un *titulo*, un *nombre* y un *apellido* y utilizando la funcion *escribirCartelito()* genera un cartelito corto o largo, según las reglas anteriores. Ejemplo:

```
 escribirCartelitoOptimo("Ing.", "Carla", "Toledo") // Retorna "Ing. Carla Toledo"
 escribirCartelitoOptimo("Dr.", "Estanislao", "Schwarzschild") // Retorna "Dr. Schwarzschild"
```

[image: esto es lo que hice yo]

[image: este es elresultado que me arrroja]

[image: esta es la funcion escribir cartelito]

Comment: Por favor leer [ask]. Las imágenes no son bien recibidas, evita usarlas para mostrar el código. Lo preferible es *copiar y pegar* el código, para proveer un [mcve]. Por otro lado, ¿Cuál es la duda o error? Saludos

Comment: Captura de pantalla ya era malo, foto de pantalla desbloquea otro nivel.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Por favor, [no publiques imágenes con código fuente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21), copia y pega directamente el código en tu pregunta. NO olvides incluir de la misma manera mensajes exactos de error. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no tienes porque utilizar una función adicional. En escribirCartelitoOptimo puedes hacer:

```
   
     return   t + '  ' +  ((''+n+a).length>15 ?  a :  n + ' ' + a);
```

Antes del n+a hay un par de comillas simples para forzar a String.